# jquploader error #302

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, upload

```
<script src="../jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="../jquery.flash.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="../jquery.jqUploader.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#example3").jqUploader({ background: "FFFFDF", barColor: "FF00FF",
                allowedExt: "*.zip",
                src: "../jqUploader.swf",
                uploadScript : "@Url.Action("Upload","Car")",
                afterScript : onRequestCompleted
            });
        });
      </script>

    <form action="@Url.Action("Upload","Car")"   class="a_form">
                <div id="example3"></div>
    </form>
```

///////////action A

```
public string Upload(HttpPostedFileBase fileData)
{

    if (this.Request.Files.Count == 0)
    {
        return "";
    }

    var fileName = this.Server.MapPath("~/AAA/" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileData.FileName));
    fileData.SaveAs(fileName);

    return "ok";
}
```

/////I used this code in 2 place. In first I used in HomeController/Upload  action A, and Html part in Home/Index.cshtml.Then jqUploader working. Bat when I moved codes: action A in Areas/AdminPanel/Controllers/CarController.cs and html in Areas/AdminPanel/Views/Car/__Extract.cshtml the jQUploader don't work and get Http #302 error.

////This code works when I use the new MVC project. But when I want to use in my project, gives error # 302. I think it's  from Global.asax.cs, and I do not know how to solve this problem  . Who can say why there might be?

Answer (score 0):

HTTP Status code 302 means your server is redirecting you to somewhere else. Find out where, by using firebug, and let me know. Also you may need to add the attribute `[HttpPost]` to your Upload action.

The most common reason for redirection is when you are not logged in and trying to access admin features. (I suspect this from looking at path `Areas/AdminPanel/Views/Car/`)  Then the server will redirect you to login page.

Check if `Authorize` attribute is listed in Global Filter in Global.asax.cs or on top of your action `Upload`. If so login, then upload.

If you are logged in then check if this jqUploader is sending the auth cookie, again, use firebug net panel XHR tab to find out all this.

Comment: In firebug XHR take 0 requests. When click upload don't sends requests.

Comment: Then how did you figure out that you were getting a 302 error? Maybe the post happens in the Net panel All tab

Comment: No I tested. There are not anyone request. I knew that error 302 from the jquploader plugin.